# Best approach to generate a third-app party file preview in Google Drive?

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, google-drive-api, phantomjs

Google Drive team has recently announced that third-party Drive app can provide their own thumbnail as a file preview (http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/10/thumbnails-for-your-custom-file-types.html).

What is for you the simplest way to achieve that? 
Our app is using AngularJS on front-end and Python webapp2 on the backend-side.

The fact that the file URL is not public and since we won't make our users' files public, it sounds harder to make it on the server-side so I started my research by looking front-end solution.

I found html2canvas (http://html2canvas.hertzen.com) which sounds great but which does not generate a correct render of our app (missing part).
I was also thinking about something with PhantomJS to generate this preview but it sounds a little bit overkill.

Thanks for your help.

**Edit**

It actually works, but Google Drive renders it in small (like 300x200px) whereas the original canvas is 630x456px. Any thoughts on this issue?
Please find the original thumbnail and its render in Google Drive attached.

[image: Original thumbnail]

[image: Rendering in Google Drive]

Answer (score 2):

I would have suggested html2canvas, but as you found out it has some limitations which may make it a non-starter. Depending on what you'd like as the preview, a full screenshot might not be necessary. If, for example, you're referring to http://www.videonot.es/, a still/thumbnail image from the video might be a sufficient preview image.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Steve. What our users are expecting from this feature is the text and the video in the notes to be able to locate a file just by seeing its preview, without opening it with our app. So we need to capture the content of the notes and note our home-page as your suggesting. 
How others Drive app developers have solved this issue?

Comment: Depends on the app and what the content is. The preview doesn't have to be a literal screenshot, just a meaningful representation of the content. I recommend *not* using a screenshot since headers/toolbars/footers/etc are all a distraction. In your case, if you can get the video thumbnail and text, you could use canvas or another other drawing mechanism to render a composite then export that to PNG.